# How do I stop VSCode from unquoting URLs?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, electron, urllib

When I open a URL in Python using VSCode, it unquotes the URL before making the request. Why is this, and how can I stop it?

Here are more details. I run this code

```py
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open('http://127.0.0.1:8000/?a=b%2Bc')
```

When I run it from the standard Python interpreter (python3.8 running on WSL2) the server logs a  `GET /?a=b%2Bc HTTP/1.1` request. When I run it from the VSCode Python terminal (connected to the same python3.8 on WSL2), the server logs a `"GET /?a=b+c HTTP/1.1` request. So it looks like something inside VSCode is intercepting the request and unquoting the URL.

**Edit.** There are many comments suggesting that it's something to do with the server. I've tested this with a [simple web server](https://github.com/nickjj/webserver) that just prints out the http request, to stdout in its own terminal window, and both the VSCode+Python client and plain bash+Python client are connecting to precisely the same web server. Here's what the webserver printed to stdout for the http request made by bash+Python:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Dec/2020 14:09:12] "GET /?a=b%2Bc HTTP/1.1" 200 -
Host: 127.0.0.1:8000
Connection: keep-alive
DNT: 1
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
Sec-Fetch-Site: none
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
```

And the http request made by VSCode+Python is exactly the same except for the first line, which is now

```
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Dec/2020 14:10:50] "GET /?a=b+c HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Comment: Where the log come from? Server side or client console?

Comment: It's a server log.

Comment: And what do you mean by "pure Python"? How do you run the code for the example that isn't in VSCode?

Comment: What version of Python are you using in VS Code? Is it the same as the version when you run in "pure Python"? Are these both on the same OS?

Comment: I'm running python3.8 on wsl2. I either start wsl2 and type "python3" at the bash prompt (this is what I'm calling pure Python), or I tell VSCode to run a terminal connecting to wsl2 and the same python3.8.

Comment: it is an electron app based on chromium but unfortunately it doesn't show network requests under "Help > Toggle Developer Tools". But this would be server's responsibility  : The ways logs are written imho. Which web server is bring used ? somehow it would be a bug on web server for specific user-agent or something

Comment: I'm running a Django webserver. I modified it to show the user-agent string, and it's identical in both cases. (As it should be. The request comes from the Python webbrowser module.) I disagree that it's an issue with server logging. The server doesn't have any information to tell where the request came from.

Comment: What it is not clear if it logs come from the same terminal or not? Will it be possible that VS code terminal has pretty output converting safe url into ASCII and your native pure python does not?

Comment: The logs are from the server. I'm running the server in separate a terminal window, on its own, and it's exactly the same server that's responding to queries from both VSCode and the Python interpreter. So there's no issue with pretty-formatting of the output.